# Expected expression before int

Tags: c

Line Col

9    22  [Error] expected expression before 'int'

14   29  [Error] expected expression before 'double'

İ am getting this error can someone fix it?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

int main()
{
    int n;
    printf("Get the number of inputs");
    scanf("%d \n",n);
    int* a = malloc (int[n]);
    int i; 
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        scanf("%d\n",a[i]);
    }
    double* average=malloc (double);
    
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        *average+=a[i]; 
    }
    *average=*average/n*1.0; 
    printf("average of all numbers is ",*average);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Turn on compiler warnings!!  It will point out several more bugs, e.g. you are using `scanf` wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by others, you have to use `sizeof()` to know the size of a datatype.
Also, `scanf()` takes pointers to the variables which will store the data you read

```
int main()
{
    int n;
    printf("Get the number of inputs\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);                 // pointer to n
    int* a = malloc (n*sizeof(int)); // <-- sizeof()
    
    int i; 
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        scanf(" %d", &a[i]); // Note the space before %d
                             // It makes scanf() skip any white space before
                             // the placeholder.
                             // You don't actually need it now, but you did
                             // in the original code after scanf("%d\n", &n)

    double average = 0; // average does not need to be allocated dinamically
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        average+=a[i]; 

    average=average/n*1.0; // 1.0 is not necessary because average is double
    printf("average of all numbers is %.3f", average);

    return 0;
}
```

You can run the code here: https://onlinegdb.com/E4Lmjk4UlU

Comment: You're right, it was needed for the original code, but then I removed the `\n` in the format string and left the other stuff.

Comment: `1.0` was in the original code and was not an issue, but you right there too

Answer (score 1):

You should use `sizeof` for obtaining size of types.

Wrong lines:

```
int* a = malloc (int[n]);
double* average=malloc (double);
```

It should be:

```
int* a = malloc (sizeof(int[n]));
double* average=malloc (sizeof(double));
```

Comment: Firstly thank you for answer but when i enter my input it is not wroking. Do you know why?

Comment: I think it should be `int* a = malloc (n * sizeof(*a));`.

Comment: Still same thing

Answer (score 1):

To expand on the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67775896/4386427

For `sizeof`I prefer:

```
int* a = malloc (n * sizeof *a);

double* average=malloc (sizeof *average);
```

This style prevents mismatch between the pointer-type and the memory allocated.

and then notice a mising initialization:

```
*average = 0;   <-------------- Initialize average

for(i=0;i<n;i++){
    *average+=a[i]; 
}
```

and

```
*average=*average/n*1.0; --> *average=*average/n;
```

the `1.0` isn't needed as `*average` is already a double.

And

```
printf("average of all numbers is ",*average);
```

has no format specifier - try:

```
printf("average of all numbers is %f",*average);
```

And your `scanf` are wrong - use

```
scanf("%d", &n);
```

and

```
scanf("%d", &a[i]);
```

Comment: This is the output i get

Comment: @Agah Check again... found one more bug